# How to automate copying a cell down another column?

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SBWuWvjBxst0owuCLefpWWsbrqv9iHYpwr1nZ6Xvi9o/edit?usp=sharing

Hi, I'm currently working to create a barcode scannning system in our warehouse. In the above spreadsheet, the barcode scanner will scan barcodes which will continue being listed down column A. However, eventually one of us will scan a QR code listing the location of the items from which we are scanning; eg. A21 (aisle A, location 2, row 1). I'd like for this location to be automatically listed for all the above empty cells on column D. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to utilize something simiar to =IF(ISBLANK(D2), “Default Value”,D2)

Check https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en

I notice you are building an app script you can review the example of  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank